# How to get a Protobuf enum value from its string representation?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go

I can get the string value of a Protobuf enum with this instruction:

```
str := testPB.Status_ENABLED.String()
```

How can I perform the inverse operation? (from a string, get the enum element).

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64461543/2270041

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The generated code has a map called `<EnumName>_value` of type `map[string]int32`. Then you can **convert** the numerical value to the actual defined type:

```
num := testPB.Status_value[str]
v := testPB.Status(num)
```

Consider that if the `str` value doesn't exist in the map (note that it's case sensitive), the map look-up will return `0`. Depending on how you defined your protobuffer, the `0` value might be mapped to a an enum instance that does not have "zero" semantics. This is why it is recommended to map `0` to an "unknown" instance:

```
enum Status {
  UNKNOWN = 0;
  ENABLED = 1;
  // and so on
}
```

Which in Go correctly yields a makeshift zero-value if the string representation is effectively unknown:

```
v := testPB.Status(testPB.Status_value["does_not_exist"]) 
fmt.Println(v == testPB.Status_UNKNOWN) // true
```

#### Go 1.18

With generics, it is possible to write reusable code to construct protobuffer enums from string values:

```
func Enum[T ~string, PB ~int32](val T, pbmap map[string]int32, dft PB) PB {
    v, ok := pbmap[string(val)]
    if !ok {
        return dft
    }
    return PB(v)
}
```

where:

- the type parameter `T` is the string representation, which could also be a type with underlying type string, e.g. `type MyEnum string`
- the argument `pbmap` is the `<EnumName>_value` from the generated protobuffer code
- the type parameter `PB` is the protobuffer enum type.

The function above takes a default value of type `PB` to (obviously) have a fallback in case the string representation is invalid, and also to allow type inference on `PB`, which otherwise would be used only as a return type.

Usage:

```
type SomeEnum string

const (
    SomeEnumFoo SomeEnum = "FOO"
    SomeEnumBar SomeEnum = "BAR"
) 

func main() {
    foo := SomeEnumFoo
    v := Enum(foo, pb.SomeEnum_value, pb.SomeEnum_Foo)
    //        ^ T  ^ map[string]int32 ^ default PB value
    // v is type pb.SomeEnum
}
```